# how to convert string into object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
var s = "{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": 10px }";
JSON.parse(s);
```

the above code throws following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 46

Comment: It is an invalid JSON string, `10px` needs to be like this: `"10px"`, so with `JSON.parse()` you can't.

Comment: String is invalid string, you can't have `"` inside `"`

Comment: You are missing a quote in `"margin": 10px` ==> `"margin": "10px"`

Comment: Your string is not a Valid json (as the error says it)you need to put " around the 10px

Answer (score 2):

Your input string is invalid.

- You cannot have `"` inside another `"`
- Also `10px` is a string so you need to wrap in quote's

Changes should be made -

```
var s = '{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": "10px" }';
JSON.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wrap 10px in quotes ("10px"), and make sure that you alternate between different quotes to not break the strings:

```
var s = '{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": "10px" }';
JSON.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your JSON syntax is incorrect, as well as your javascript syntax.

Your JSON should have keys which are strings, and values which are strings. At the moment your `10px` is not a string. You need to change this to `"10px"`

Moreover, your quotes within your string which you use for the object's keys/values break the string itself. You can either use backticks, backslashes or single quotes to encapsulate your string properly (without breaking the string):

**Single quotes:**

```
var s = '{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": "10px" }';
```

**Backslashes:**

```
var s = "{\"background-color\": \"#4a90e2\", \"margin\": \"10px\"}";
```

**Backticks:**

```
var s = `{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": "10px" }`;
```

See working example below:

```js
var s = "{\"background-color\": \"#4a90e2\", \"margin\": \"10px\"}";
console.log(JSON.parse(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different types of quotes!
This would work: `'{ "background-color": "#4a90e2", "margin": "10px" }'`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shouldn't 10px be a string? Kindly adjust that...

Comment: already there are so many answers stating the same, what's new in yours?

Comment: I answered before similar answers popped up, it's probably the network.